# Send messages to devices on a LAN

Tags: internet, connection, lan

We are setting up a small computer gang and want to have a LAN with a chat channel, but without the need to connect to the WAN and use external services like whatsapp or signal etc.

Is there any way/software recommended cross platform or unix specific to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For extremely simple inter-unix chat ytalk/utalk (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man1/utalk.1.html) comes to mind, if cross-platform or a GUI is required, we have had some good inter-office chats with BeeBEEP (https://www.beebeep.net).